# Can somebody tell me what I have done wrong to IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, java-17

When I start IntelliJ I have some alert like:

```
    Internal error. Please refer to https://jb.gg/ide/critical-startup-errors

com.intellij.ide.plugins.StartupAbortedException: UI initialization failed
    at com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil.lambda$start$15(StartupUtil.java:265)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniExceptionally(CompletableFuture.java:990)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniExceptionally.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:974)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:510)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postFire(CompletableFuture.java:614)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniRun.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:795)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$Completion.run(CompletableFuture.java:482)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:318)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:771)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:722)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:716)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:741)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil (in unnamed module @0x1806bff2) cannot access class sun.awt.AWTAutoShutdown (in module java.desktop) because module java.desktop does not export sun.awt to unnamed module @0x1806bff2
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.encodeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:315)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:320)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniRun.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:791)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil (in unnamed module @0x1806bff2) cannot access class sun.awt.AWTAutoShutdown (in module java.desktop) because module java.desktop does not export sun.awt to unnamed module @0x1806bff2
    at com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil.lambda$scheduleInitUi$23(StartupUtil.java:507)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniRun.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:787)
    ... 14 more

-----
Your JRE: 17+35-LTS-2724 amd64 (Oracle Corporation)
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17
```

And:

```
    Internal error. Please refer to https://jb.gg/ide/critical-startup-errors

java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil (in unnamed module @0x1806bff2) cannot access class sun.awt.AWTAutoShutdown (in module java.desktop) because module java.desktop does not export sun.awt to unnamed module @0x1806bff2
    at com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil.start(StartupUtil.java:297)
    at com.intellij.idea.Main.bootstrap(Main.java:123)
    at com.intellij.idea.Main.main(Main.java:84)

-----
Your JRE: 17+35-LTS-2724 amd64 (Oracle Corporation)
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17
```

I've added wrong path to JRE so I hope somebody can help me
I think it come from I linked the path to JDK 17 instead of JRE 17. But, now I can't start IntelliJ to fix. So I nedd your help.
Thank for all.
Sorry about my bad English.

Comment: Nah, cuz it's my team project and using IntelliJ is maybe compulsory

Comment: Are you using community version or Ultimate version?

Comment: Yeah, I'm sure that I'm using the free version

Answer (score 2):

There is a link in the error.

> Internal error. Please refer to https://jb.gg/ide/critical-startup-errors

From that

I think the exception is due to some plugins.

Please try this:-

### If you are using 2019.3.x and below versions

- Close IDE If open
- Go to **`C:\Users\<Username>\.IntelliJIdea2019.3\config`**(Syntax:- `%HOMEPATH%\\.<product><version>\config`)
- Delete the **plugins** Directory
- Restart IDE

### If you are using 2020.1 and above versions

- Close IDE If open
- Go to **`C:\Users\<Username>\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2021.2`**(Syntax:- `%APPDATA%\JetBrains\<product><version>`)
- Delete **plugins** Directory
- Restart IDE

Comment: I've deleted the plugins Directory but I still can't start the IDE

Comment: Try reinstalling

Comment: 2 times and still no :(

Comment: Okay Clear the cache of IDE and also clear all the temporary files

Comment: If it didn't work uninstall unwanted plugins.

Comment: Tks for your advice ;)

Comment: @KhôiPhạmHuy Welcome

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238424/discussion-between-khoi-phm-huy-and-jfan).